# New Picklist value not showing only in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, picklist

I added a new value to an existing picklist (not dependent field).
I added it to the record type and I see it in the record layout.

BUT I can't see it in a custom lightning component which displays the field using `lightning:inputField`. All values are showing except this one.

Has anyone know what do in that case ?

Comment: are you using correct recordtypeid in lightning recordform

Comment: Your answer got me to the resolution. I didn't enter recordTypeId in the lightning recordEditForm since the component is only for update the record. And the new value was added only to one record type (and not all of them). So that's why it wasn't showing in the component. Thanks.

Comment: Could one of you please post an answer with the resolution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your org uses record types, picklist fields display values according to your record types. You must provide a record type ID using the record-type-id attribute if you have multiple record types on an object and you don't have a default record type. Otherwise, the default record type ID is used.